# Double and triple integrals - does the order of integration matter? What does f(x,y,z) "do"?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume

I have not found anything about it, that's why I am asking it here.

As far as I know, the volume is:
$$V=\iiint_E dxdydz$$
But does the order of dx, dy, dz matter? For example, if i can define the dy's limit with x and z, the dz's limit with x, and the dx's limit with constants, can i just simply write dydzdx?

And the other question: What does the f(x,y,z) "do" here?
$$V=\iiint f(x,y,z) dxdydz$$
As I know, the mass can be calculated like this:
$$m=\iiint \rho(x,y,z) dxdydz$$
But here the result is mass, not volume.

Comment: Of course it matters *if* the corresponding limits aren't constants. That's why we'd rather write $$V=\iiint_E dV$$ As for your second question: you can always think of $\;f\;$ as a density function...

Comment: In general, if $f$ represents the amount of "stuff" per volume, then $\iiint_E  f\,dV$ is the total amount of stuff.  The same is true for double integrals: if $f$ is the total amount of "stuff" per area, then $\iint_R f\,dA$ is the total amount of stuff.  When $f$ measures mass per area, the integral yields total mass.  When $f$ measures volume per area (as it does when it represents the height of a graph over the $xy$-plane), then $\iint_E f\,dA$ yields total volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrals are in first place integrals with respect to three-dimensional measure:
$$\int_E1\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)\ ,\quad {\rm resp.},\quad\int_Ef(x,y,z)\>{\rm d}(x,y,z)\ ,$$
and they are limits of Riemannian sums of the following kind:
$$\sum_{k=1}^N f({\bf r}_k)\>{\rm vol}(E_k)\ ,$$
whereby the $E_k$ form a partition of $E$ into almost disjoint  "bricks" $E_k$.

Fubini's theorem tells us that such an integral can be written as a threefold nested  integral, called a *triple integral* for short. If $E$ is convex such a triple  integral looks like
$$\int_a^b\int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}\int_{p(x,y)}^{q(x,y)}f(x,y,z)\>dz\>dy\>dx\ .\tag{1}$$
In order to determine the limits $c(x)$, $\ldots$, $q(x,y)$ appearing here you have to use the full and precise geometric description of $E$. The order of the nesting  in $(1)$ is irrelevant, but the limits appearing in the integrals of course depend on the chosen order.

Comment: Could you elaborate in the first line where the $f(x,y,z)$ in the integral after "resp" came from (i.e. it is in the right integral but not the left one, why?)

Comment: The first integral, giving the volume of $E$,  is the special case $f(x,y,z)\equiv1$ of the second. Usually the $f$ does not come from nowhere, but  is prescribed by our customer, having geometric, physical, or other applications in mind..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define the order of integration as you want of dxdydz you just have to change the limit of integration.
secondly,
 here in your case f(x,y,z) is mass per unit volume
in general it is density function