# Confusion in integrating $\int_0^2\int_0^x\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) \ dxdydz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

**Question:**
$$\int_0^2\int_0^x\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) \ dxdydz$$

---

I solved this question without any problem and [verified my answer from wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cint_0%5E2%5Cint_0%5Ex%5Cint_0%5E%7Bx%2By%7D+e%5Ex+%28y%2B2z%29+dxdydz). The reason I'm posting this question is that, my friend solved it another way and got answer $\dfrac{19}{3}(e^2 +3)$. He changes the original integral and evaluated $\displaystyle\int_0^2\int_0^x\left[\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z)dz\right] \ dxdy$. I know that we cannot do that, just want to confirm it here.

When I asked him, he said "In multiple integrals, we can integrate $x$ with $x$ as a variable in limits, it's a rule."

I know that $dxdydz$ represents the order of the triple integral and we cannot change it unless the limits are constants.

Am I wrong? How can I make him realise his method is wrong? (In case I'm not wrong).

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294786/double-and-triple-integrals-does-the-order-of-integration-matter-what-does-f#:~:text=Double%20and%20triple%20integrals%20%2D%20does%20the%20order%20of%20integration%20matter%3F%20What%20does%20f(x%2Cy%2Cz)%20%22do%22%3F) question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the integral in the title has no sense, because the same variable of integration cannot appear in the limits. My guess (and that of other comments) is that there is a typo in the order of differentials, so that it can be solved by nested integrals:
$$
\int_0^2\int_0^x\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) \ dz dy dx = \int_0^2 \left(\int_0^x\left(\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) \ dz \right)dy \right)dx
$$

Having said this, I have to admit that this is a somewhat forgivable error. The point is that there is only one admissible ordering to avoid any cyclic dependance. In this way, the limit for $z$ is $z=\phi(x,y)$, the limit for $y$ is $y=\varphi(x)$, and the limits for $x$ are constant. So I interpret $dxdydz$ as *any ordering of the variables that makes sense*.

As a practical advice, I would also suggest being aware of the context: if this exercise appears in the chapter of multiple integrals by Fubini's Theorem, then the ordering has to lead you to the correct solution. Also check if this was the original problem, or an intermediate step where you have converted a region into specific integral limits. That conversion can lead to an incorrect ordering of variables.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it seems your friend is incorrectly applying [Fubini's Theorem](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/IteratedIntegrals.aspx), which only applies to rectangular regions or prisms where the limits of integration are constants and not functions of another variable.

When we apply Fubini's anyway, we have to change the order of the integral signs if we change the order of the differentials. Additionally, if the region is not a prism or rectangle, we have to make sure that the limits of integration still represent the region in question in terms of the new order of variables.

Comment: The integral $\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) \ dx$ is not correct either, because the same variable of integration cannot appear in the limits.

Comment: @Miguel what should we do then? ._.

Comment: Yes, @Miguel I looked at this more closely too and noticed the same thing. OP, I would check whether or not that problem has a typo -- my guess is that it does.

Comment: Perhaps it is supposed to be $\int_0^2\int_0^x\int_0^{x+y} e^x (y+2z) dzdydx$?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only possible way to read this integral is by deducing from the upper boundaries that the third integral can only apply to $dz$, the second one then only to $dy$, and the first one (hence) to $dx$.
So I agree with the result reached by you friend. Interestingly enough, Wolfram needs a suggestive order of differentials: you need to feed it with $dzdydx$ in order to get the same result.